# How to add timeout to a rundeck job

Tags: timeout, rundeck

I have a specific job in rundeck that I need to add a timeout to - what is the process - can I just add on option: -timeout:1200000 (20 minutes)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can edit the job through rundeck's UI. Here is a snapshot.

[image]

Go to edit job, you will find the timeout option.